# Get count from DynamoDB resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Is there a way to get count of items returned by DynamoDB query from AppSync API?

DDB projection COUNT is not supported in AppSync, also I can't write something like `${context.result.items.count}` in response mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Quick workaround (will not work for 1MB+ results): define scalar return value for the query in schema and use in response resolver `$util.toJson($ctx.result.items.size())`